# Prove that $\prod_{d|n} d = n^{\frac{τ(n)}{2}}$

Tags: number-theory

Prove that 
 $\prod_{d|n} d = n^{\frac{τ(n)}{2}}$

Comment: You should both type using LaTeX, to make your stuff crystal clear, and add some explanations, e.g.: it "seems obvious" that $\,\tau\,$ is some kind of arithmetical function...but which one?

Answer (score 5):

$d$ is a divisor of $n$ if and only if $\frac{n}{d}$ is a divisor of $n$.

Then

$$\prod_{d|n} d =\prod_{d |n} \frac{n}{d}$$

Thus,

$$ \left( \prod_{d|n} d  \right)^2= \prod_{d|n} d  \cdot \prod_{d |n} \frac{n}{d}= \prod_{d|n} n$$

You don't need to split it in to cases, that split was probably suggested by someone who expected you to group the $d$ and $\frac{n}{d}$ terms in $\prod_{d|n} d$... In that case, if $n=k^2$, you cannot group $k$ with $\frac{n}{k}=k$....

Comment: Yes, it works in that case, but there is no need to discuss the two cases separately ;)